# junit5 is not picking up tests

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I have simple test

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

 public class MyTestClass{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTestClass.class);

    private static final Long timeout = 5000L;

    @Test
    public void test(){
        Assertions.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

And i tried to run it with `mvn test -Dtest=MyTestClass#test test`,but got error:

> Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test
> (default-test) on project TestProject: No tests
> were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)

when i tried to run it with intellij:

> Internal Error occurred. org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException:
> TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests   at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:111)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:85)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:92)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
> at
> com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/junit/jupiter/api/ClassOrderer    at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.config.DefaultJupiterConfiguration.(DefaultJupiterConfiguration.java:50)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:66)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:103)
> ... 7 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)     ... 10 more
>
> Process finished with exit code -2

My depenendices are following:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <dependencies>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
            <printSummary>true</printSummary>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>integration/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

and

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

why cannot maven nor intellij execuite Junit5 tests? What is the work around for this? The surefire version should already support JUnit5 tests.

Comment: Does adding the following dependency solve the issue: 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to `5.8.2` - I had the same issue occur literally overnight with no changes, and upgrading to the latest Jupiter version resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

Add `<includes>*</includes>` to surefire configuration.

I had the same issue, including all explicitely helped.
I'm running this config with surefire `3.0.0-M3`.